# An error occured with Nokogiri while bundle install (OSx Mavericks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

i'm new in rails and i don't understand why Nokogiri don't want to install while i try to bundle install :

```
barnab21:sample_app barnab21$ sudo bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as
root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake 0.9.6
Using abstract 1.0.0
Using activesupport 3.0.7
Using builder 2.1.2
Using i18n 0.5.4
Using activemodel 3.0.7
Using erubis 2.6.6
Using rack 1.2.8
Using rack-mount 0.6.14
Using rack-test 0.5.7
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using actionpack 3.0.7
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.2.20
Using actionmailer 3.0.7
Using arel 2.0.10
Using activerecord 3.0.7
Using activeresource 3.0.7
Using diff-lcs 1.1.3
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Building nokogiri using system libraries.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**I try this** :

```
 $ xcode-select --install
```

then gem install nogoriki, but that doesn't work.

**I try this, from a other stackoverflow thread** :

If previously installed, uninstall the gem:

```
$ gem uninstall nokogiri
```

Use Homebrew to install libxml2, libxslt and libiconv if needed:

```
$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv
```

Install the gem specifying the paths to the libraries to be linked against:

```
$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"
```

And :

```
This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I Don't know what to try... thx
My mac : Macbook pro retina 15 , mavericks

Comment: This is the problem: `libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!` You need to make sure that's installed on your Mac first.

Answer (score 4):

After `$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv` I used

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
```

and it works for me. You can try it, but change versions of libraries to yours.

Comment: Thx i try : 

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib

But doesn't work..i have always the same error. Do you think i need to change other things ? i just change version of libraries

Comment: Check all of your paths in command and ensure that you have libraries in this directories. You may also try this: `brew link libxml2 libxslt libiconv`, but brew have to link it after installation.

Comment: Latest `nokogori` doesn't seem to need `libiconv`. The following worked in my case: `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.1 -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28`. Check your Cellar tree for proper version numbers; and, of course, replace by the `nokogiri` version you are interested in.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I get : ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
Dregir:derbyhouse gkemp$

Answer (score 0):

So I'm on Yosemite, thought this might help.
The solutions above didn't work for me, but then I realized a couple of the directories had somehow gotten moved into themselves

> --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/**libxml**
>
> --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/**lib**

So it might be worth checking all the directories, if anyone still has the problem (ha I don't think I put the files like that, but it's totally possible)

The full command I used:

> gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/libxml --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/lib

Answer (score 0):

got same problem in Redhat linux 6

you need to install packages libxml2 & libxml2-devel and libxslt & libxslt-devel.

{you need to install libgcrypt & libgcrpt-devel as it is required to install above packages }

make sure you install latest versions.
if package already exist then you need to upgrade those packages.
just use

### rpm -uvh --replacefiles {your_packagename.rpm}

hope it helps. comment if you need more help.